# suffixes in xts merge in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

When trying to `merge` to `xts` objects, it doesn't look like the `suffixes` arg is working properly:

```
require(xts)
x <- xts(1:10, seq.Date(from=as.Date("2012-01-01"), len=10, by=1))
y <- xts(11:20, seq.Date(from=as.Date("2012-01-01"), len=10, by=1))

names(x) <- "x"
names(y) <- "x"

merge(x,y,suffixes=c("truex", "truey"))

            x x.1
2012-01-01  1  11
2012-01-02  2  12
2012-01-03  3  13
2012-01-04  4  14
2012-01-05  5  15
2012-01-06  6  16
2012-01-07  7  17
2012-01-08  8  18
2012-01-09  9  19
2012-01-10 10  20
```

Am I misusing?

Comment: This isn't a question.  If you think this is a bug, you should submit a bug report and/or email the package maintainer.

Comment: the question was implied. i wanted to know if i was using things incorrectly. thanks for pointing out. if this is actually a bug i'll submit.

Comment: this is a useful question, just helped me, and should not be "closed". Data venia, even if it is a bug, documenting it here is useful. The answer below is useful too.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Is there any chance this bug is going to be fixed? https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/38

Comment: @stucash I think I [have a fix](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/commit/d3bbcc7cd44620ad0a2fe5260e9bdff83008fb88). I'd greatly appreciate it if you could try to break it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While `merge.xts` seems to be broken, `merge.zoo` does work:

```
> merge.zoo(x,y,suffixes=c("truex", "truey"))
           x.truex x.truey
2012-01-01       1      11
2012-01-02       2      12
2012-01-03       3      13
2012-01-04       4      14
2012-01-05       5      15
2012-01-06       6      16
2012-01-07       7      17
2012-01-08       8      18
2012-01-09       9      19
2012-01-10      10      20
```